# wxPython - wxGrid - How to detect which column moves where

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

When the user drags a column to a new index, the `wx.grid.EVT_GRID_COL_MOVE` event is triggered. The handler receives a `wx.grid.GridEvent` which contains the property `Col` which contains the old index of the moved column. The event doesn't appear to contain any attributes detailing where the column has been moved *to* though. How do I figure that out?

Answer (score 2):

In case of the`EVT_GRID_COL_MOVE` event, `GridEvent.GetCol()` returns the **ID** of the column that is being moved. The actual position of the column can be obtained with `Grid.GetColPos(colId)`. However,
there's a difference between wxWidgets 2.8 and wx 2.9:

In `wx 2.8`, `EVT_GRID_COL_MOVE` is sent **after** the column has been moved which would prevent you from vetoing the event.
Therefore calling `GetColPos()` during the event will return the *new* position of the column.

In `wx 2.9`, `EVT_GRID_COL_MOVE` is triggered **before** the column is moved and vetoing the event will prevent the column from being moved.
Calling `GetColPos()` during the event will return the *current* position of the column.

The new position of the column is calculated internally, based on the mouse position. 
Duplicating that code in python may conflict with future releases which may break the program.

Using `wx 2.9+` you can implement a workaround that will give you the new column position and allows you to 'veto' (or rather undo) the move:

```
self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_COL_MOVE, self.OnColMove)
```

```
def OnColMove(self,evt):
    colId = evt.GetCol()
    colPos = self.grid.GetColPos(colId)
    wx.CallAfter(self.OnColMoved,colId,colPos)
    # allow the move to complete

def OnColMoved(self,colId,oldPos):
    # once the move is done, GetColPos() returns the new position
    newPos = self.grid.GetColPos(colId)
    print colId, 'from', oldPos, 'to', newPos
    undo = False
    if undo: # undo the move (as if the event was veto'd)
        self.grid.SetColPos(colId,oldPos)
```

Note that `SetColPos` will be called twice if the move has to be undone (once internally and a second time in `OnColMoved`).

Alternatively you could look into `wx.lib.gridmovers`.

Comment: +1 Incredibly good answer. I will comment further when I've had a chance to try it out.